# While Loop and Showing Images from a Folder With SQL

Tags: php

I have a list of images within a file. The file name along with details about the image are stored in a mysql table. I have created a while loop that randomly generates several images on my page. There is a problem however. My webpage is not producing any images. I have narrowed it down to the function I created clothing_data. I'm just stumped at what I need to do. Here is the code below.

```
<?php
function clothing_data ($id) {
    $data = array();
    $id = (int)$id; 
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();   
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {   
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields ='`' .  implode ('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `dress` WHERE `primary_id` = $id"));
    return $data;
    }
}

$num_dresses = dress_count ();

$i = 0;    
while ($i < 5)
{   
    $rand_id = rand(1, $num_dresses);
    $dress_feed_data = clothing_data($rand_id, 'file_name', 'user_defined_name', 
'user_defined_place' , 'user_who_uploaded');
    echo $dress_feed_data['file_name'];
    if (file_exists('fashion_images/' . $dress_feed_data['file_name']))
    {
?>

<br>
<img src="fashion_images/<?php echo $dress_feed_data['file_name'];?>" width="50" height="50" />
<?php
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Careful about `mysql_` functions... they're deprecated, and you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'm sure there is a lot I can fix on this code. One step at a time.

Comment: Why are you passing additional parameters to `clothing_data` when it only accepts `$id`.

Comment: Because each parameter (which is a name of a column in my table dress) allows me to pull that field connected to the primary id or $id. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it just confused me for a sec.

Comment: @jason328: are u storing file extension in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. There were multiple issues involved. For one my primary id was not linked up to the randomly generated ids that were inside my database. The other reason it was not working was because the fields relating to the name of my filename were not the same ones found in my images folder. This is because when the name of the file is inserted into my database a space is added to the name making it impossible to link the name on my database to the name in my folder. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<img>` tag `$dress_feed_data[file_name]` should be  `$dress_feed_data['file_name']`.

Comment: The page is rendering I just do not see the actual images. No errors. I checked to see if the file exist function within the if statement works and it does. I suspect it has to do with the line of code that has the img tag.

Comment: I would just have a play around with what `echo $dress_feed_data['file_name'];` puts out to try and get the URL right.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `$field` is either empty or contains a wrong column name or other error. What do you get when you `var_dump()`?

Since you already defining the columns in `$dress_feed_data = clothing_data($rand_id, 'file_name', 'user_defined_name', 
'user_defined_place' , 'user_who_uploaded');`

you could simply just change your function to something like-

```
function clothing_data ($id, $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4) {
    $data = array();
    $id = (int)$id; 
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();   
    $fields ='`' .  $field1 . '`, `' .  $field2 . '`, `' .  $field3 . '`, `' .  $field4 . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `dress` WHERE `primary_id` = $id"));
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: I ran var_dump($dress_feed_data); and was returned with bool(false) 5 times.

Comment: What do you get if you put var_dump($field) within function clothing_data()?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I took out the var_dump() which was in the while loop and then put var_dump($fields); into the clothing_data function. The bool(false) disappears and returns to the original issue, that no image is shown except five icons each showing a page torn in half. There are no errors.

Comment: I think `$dress_feed_data['file_name']` is empty. Try changing     $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `dress` WHERE `primary_id` = $id"));  --  TO --     $data = mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `dress` WHERE `primary_id` = $id")) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I didn't receive a mysql error but the rest of the script died. Is there a problem with the query then?

Comment: Your query problem is most likely caused by (1) connection to mysql or database, ie. `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); mysql_select_db($database);`, (2) `$field` is not correct, or (3) `$id` is not correct. You may have to debug each of those to find the issue.

Comment: I found out that within my database the primary_id's were in the double digits range, making the randomly generated number used to select a random picture void. I fixed it yet it is still not producing an image. And also my if statement regarding if the file exists is returning false when before it was returning true.